# Why does IndexOf return -1?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am learning Javascript and don't understand why the indexOf below returns -1:

```
var string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

console.log (string.indexOf("good"));
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

-1 means "no match found".

The reason it returns -1 instead of "false" is that a needle at the beginning of the string would be at position 0, which is equivalent to false in Javascript. So returning -1 ensures that you know there is not actually a match.

Comment: "The reason it returns -1 instead of "false" is that a needle at the beginning of the string would be at position 0, which is equivalent to false in Javascript. So returning -1 ensures that you know there is not actually a match." If you use strict comparison like `0 === false` JS returns `false` (same with `undefined` and `null`), so there doesn't seem to be any reason why use `-1`, since you can check all those more intuitive values. JS arelady has two "empty" values - `undefined` and `null`, why not use of those?.

Answer (score 13):

-1 means no match found. "good" is not in that sentence. This is [documented](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) [behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

Answer (score 11):

Because arrays are 0 based, returning 0 would mean starting from the first character was matched; 1, the second character, and so on. This means anything 0 and up would be a true or "found" response. To keep everything in the integer category, -1 signifies no match found.

Answer (score 3):

There is another reason for indexOf to return -1 when no match is found. Consider the code below:

```
if (~str.indexOf(pattern)){
  console.log('found')
}else{
  console.log('not found')
}
```

Because ~(-1) = 0 so the fact that indexOf returning -1 makes it easier to write if...else using ~.

Answer (score 0):

The search never finds what it's looking for ("good" isn't in the sentence), and -1 is the default return value.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

Related issue; even if the subject word exists in the sentence (semantically speaking) or any sequence of letters matching partially, indexOf() would return the index of its first matching letter. e.g.

```
const string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
console.log(string.length);
// expected output: 43

console.log (string.indexOf("fox"));
// expected output: 16

console.log (string.indexOf(" q"));
// expected output: 3
```

But if the partial sequence of letters is not matching any part of the string array, the method will return -1, the same case with "good";

```
console.log (string.indexOf("foxy"));
// expected output: -1

console.log (string.indexOf("good"));
// expected output: -1
```

Just in case, turning it to an array of sub-strings (here the words) is possible with split() method, splitting the long string by its spaces (punctuations);

```
const words = string.split(' ');
console.log(words);
// expected output: ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]

console.log(words.indexOf("fox"));
// expected output: 3
```